# Prove $ν(A) := \int_Afd\mu =\int_{\Omega}f\mathbf{1_A} d\mu, \quad ∀A\in \mathscr{F},$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ a non-negative
extended Borel function. Then,
$$ν(A) := \int_Afd\mu =\int_{\Omega}f\mathbf{1_A} d\mu, \quad ∀A\in \mathscr{F},$$
defines a measure on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$

I have no idea how to prove this, especially the second equality I was taking it as granted.

Sincerely asking for help

Comment: I think that is precisely the definition of $\int_A$, so you can take it for granted. What you need to check is not that, but rather the properties of a measure